# TextOverFlow Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a certain Text widget , when it overflows I have 3 options. Either fade ,visible, ellipsis or clip. But I don't want to choose between them . I want if a text has overflow then don't show the text.

**Edit :**
I'm working on a code clone to this [design](https://dribbble.com/shots/6848907-Onboarding-App-Menu)

Assuming that the textStyle is **unknown**. 
How could I achieve that?

**Code:**

```
class SwipeNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  SwipeNavigationBar({this.child});
  @override
  _SwipeNavigationBarState createState() => _SwipeNavigationBarState();
}

class _SwipeNavigationBarState extends State<SwipeNavigationBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Controller>(
      builder: (_, _bloc, __) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 01),
            color: Colors.white,
            curve: Curves.easeIn,
            height: !_bloc.x ? 50 : 200,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(child: Icon(Icons.dashboard)),
                    Expanded(
                      child: RotatedBox(
                        quarterTurns: -45,
                        child: Text(
                          'data', 
                          softWrap: false,  
                          style: TextStyle(
                            textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mimic the design you might want to look into using the `Stack` widget. However, to answer your question, you'd want to set `softWrap` to `false`.

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  child: SizedBox(
    width: 100,
    child: Text(
      'Some text we want to overflow',
      softWrap: false,
    ),
  ),
)
```

`softWrap` is really the key here. Although, I added the `Align` and `SizedBox` widgets to allow this to be used anywhere, regardless of what parent widget you are using (since some widgets set tight constraints on their children and will override their children's size preference).

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/SupposedlySam/pen/MWaEwgg)

### Edit: 5/6/2020

With the release of [Flutter v1.17](https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-flutter-1-17-4182d8af7f8e) you now have access to a new `Widget` called [NavigationRail](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html) which may help you with the design you're looking for.

[image: Navigation Rail Example]

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator to check the length of the text that you are passing to the Text widget and based on that pass the text itself or an empty string.

```
String yourText;
int desiredLengthToShow = 10; //Change this according to you.
...
Text(
  child: yourText.length > desiredLengthToShow ? "" : yourText,
);
```

Comment: That'll work if the text size & the media query are known.a 2 letter length 40sp font-Size input can have the same overflow of 10 letters 19sp font-Size.  But the thing is , the inserted text properties aren't known (such as text size or text color etc..) . So that'll be a problem.

Comment: Can you share your code, Its hard to understand how the incoming data will have styling properties!